# Fade in word with JQuery

Tags: jquery, fade, appendchild

I tried looking at the different blogs but still not sure how to set this up. I am trying to convert my original to jQuery and well I am having issues creating a fading effect since I am appending the word and not sure how I need to change my code.

Of course if you need to see my whole js file let me know. Thank you for any help guys

```
function listWordsUsed(wordUsed) {
    var userTrials = document.getElementById("userGuesses");
    var divisor = document.createElement("div");
    divisor.innerHTML = "<div id=" + wordUsed + ">" + $(this).fadeIn(5000); + "</div>";
    userTrials.appendChild(divisor);
    return;
} //End of function listWordsUsed(wordUsed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using full blown jQuery:

```
function listWordsUsed(wordUsed) {
    var userTrials = $('#userGuesses');
    var divisor = $("<div><div id=" + wordUsed + "></div></div>");
    divisor.hide().appendTo(userTrials).fadeIn(5000);
    return;
} //End of function 

listWordsUsed(wordUsed);
```

If you're trying to append the word guessed, then you should change the code slightly:

```
var divisor = $("<div>" + wordUsed + "</div>");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dtc3qLz2/1/)